# I can't install "SQL Server 2019" in windows 11. Getting error 0x84B40002

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-11

I can't install "SQL Server 2019" in windows 11. Getting error 0x84B40002 stating Database service engine failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A simple Google search on the error code returned some useful hits. Also, try looking at the setup error log and provide more details about what the error is and maybe someone here can help you.